# What to do when no one answer a question, and you don't have enough rep to offer a bounty?

Tags: discussion, questions

Unfortunately, I had a late-night doubt recently, which meant (that I realized later on) I wouldn't probably get many replies ([this was the question](https://serverfault.com/questions/299861/lamp-server-for-wordpress-blog-setup-with-apc-caching-and-cdn-good/299885#comment-285688)). I got just one reply, but I need more input from the experienced community of sysadmins at ServerFault.

I do not have enough rep. to offer a bounty and feature the question. What should I do under circumstances like this? Asking the same question again, but in different tone, is one. But is it considered spamming? Please advise.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the quick answers. I normally edit my questions many times for the sake of clarity, but I never realized that I was actually bumping them. LOL!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bump your question back up the list by editing the question text to ***improve*** the question.

Comment: But don't just add nonsense like *"any answers yet?"*

Comment: @Michael Petrotta right! noted.

Answer (score 11):

Definitely not ask the question again.

Instead, modify your question. This serves two purposes:

- You can add extra clarification about what is being asked, possibly as results of previous answers and comments, and
- It bumps the question in the recently active list to the top so it gets new attraction for answering.